# Perl ithreads: Do some math instead of sleeping

Tags: multithreading, perl, sleep

I am using perl ithreads and things work fine, unless I decide to have threads sleep.

Lets say my routine thread_job is passed as an entry for several threads to start running concurrently.

```
thread_job()
{
...
sleep 2;

#do other stuff here

}
```

If I dont have a sleep I have no issues with the threads running and they do their tasks fine. If I add a sleep, my script hangs. I am running this off a windows command prompt, if that helps.

Since I do need to sleep and Im guessing there's an issue with using this sleep on my current setup, I intend to have the thread do something, for a while, instead of sleeping. Is there any such mathematical operation which I could perform?

Comment: What version of Perl are you running? if I recall, there were issues with the core sleep on windows in older versions of Perl.

Comment: Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 8 subversion 8) configuration:

Comment: If you can, upgrade to a more modern Perl. 5.12.2 was released a few days ago, whereas 5.8.8 is... uh... quite old. Upgrading may not solve this problem, but it'll get you a supported version of Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Win32::Sleep](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32#Win32::Sleep(TIME)) instead. (Note that it takes *milliseconds* as an argument, not seconds.)

Comment: @decafa5c11: in that case please feel free to accept the answer (click on the outlined checkmark next to the answer). :)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `sleep()` blocks the entire process (that is all the threads).

You can instead block a single thread by calling `select()`. Do something like this:

```
thread_job() {
...
$delay = 2;
select(undef, undef, undef, $delay);
...
}
```